# Zend Framework 3 filter / validate array of contents

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I've searched internet and there is no official documentation for applying input filters to arrays in ZF3.

I have seen answers for ZF2, [Zend Framework 2 filter / validate array of contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293870/zend-framework-2-filter-validate-array-of-contents)

Can anyone help out how to apply input filters to array of input.

This is my form class

```
class ContactForm extends Form
{
 public function __construct($name = null)
{
    // we want to ignore the name passed
    parent::__construct("contactForm");
    $this->addInputFilters();
}

public function init()
{
    $this->add([
        "name"                       => "Type[]",
        "type"                       => "text",
        "attributes"                 => [
            "class"                  => "form-control",
        ],
    ]);
}
private function addInputFilters() {
    $inputFilter->add([
        "name"                       => "Type[]",
        "required"                   => true,
        "filters"                    => [],
        "validators"                 => [
            [
                "name"               => "StringLength",
                "options"            => [
                    "min"            => 3,
                    "max"            => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `(new InputFilterClass())->setData(['dataKey'=>'dataValue'])->isValid()` ?

Comment: Either update or delete the question please. Flagged for closing.

Answer (score 0):

This page has the answer for you https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Collecting_User_Input_with_Forms/Adding_Form_Filtering_and_Validation_Rules.html .

The first difference I can see is the method name that is not addInputFilters but addInputFilter, without 's'.

Also within addInputFilter you did not get the form input filter with

> $inputFilter = $this->getInputFilter();

infact in you example you are calling 'add' to an undefined variable actually, but perhaps your posted example is not the ful code.

Also, if you want to validate collection ( wich kind of data is going to validate 'Type[]'? ), use Collection input filter, and assign to it an input filter to validate each entry.